# Terraform event monitor migration

Tags: terraform, datadog

Trying to migrate event monitors according to [migration steps](https://docs.datadoghq.com/events/guides/migrating_to_new_events_features/)

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "cache_event" {
  name    = "${var.cache_replication_group} :: Event"
  type    = "event-v2 alert"
  message = join(" ", ["Cache event occured in ${var.cache_replication_group}.", join(" ", var.recipients.general)])

  query = "events(\"source:elasticache tags:(replication_group:${var.cache_replication_group}) NOT(Finished)\").rollup(\"count\").last(\"15m\") > 0"
  require_full_window = false

  tags = concat(var.tags, ["cache:${var.cache_replication_group}", "monitor:stability"])
}
```

But when trying to apply changes Terraform returns the error `Error: error creating monitor: event-v2 alert is not a valid MonitorType`, but according to their [documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/monitors/#create-a-monitor) `event-v2 alert` is a valid type. DataDog provider version at the moment is `3.10.0`, hence it should support this [type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/monitor)

Comment: Does the `required_providers` section have the version of the provider you want?

Comment: Yes, `version = "~> 3.10.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. After changing the provider version, I didn't reinitialise the state file.

Edit:
Before monitor migration, I used an older DataDog provider version. After adjusting query to be complient with a new event monitor format, I bumped DataDog provider version to the one that supports new `v2` monitors, but instead of deleting `.terraform` folder and triggering `init` Terraform command, I just went straight with `apply`. Instead I should have initialized it first (`init`).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).